# I want to set the last layer of neural network in matlab into sigmoid instead of classifier

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I most examples I've found about neural network based on Matlab, the last layer they using is  classifier with softmax or regressionLayer, as below :

```
layers =[sequenceInputLayer([inputs) fullyConnectedLayer(128) fullyConnectedLayer(128) clippedReluLayer(1)
fullyConnectedLayer(output) regressionLayer];
```

My question, what's about if I want to make the last later sigmoid ? is that possible to do that in Matlab based neural network ?

thank you

Comment: I think those 2 are not interchangeable. What do you mean sigmoid? That the output of your entire network is simply a value between 0-1 ? I mean, to start with, its very likely that each of the outputs of the classifier have a sigmoid applied to them. A priori, this question looks like misunderstanding of concepts. If its not, can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes sigmoid layer mean the outputs are simply take values between 0 and 1

Comment: That is not a "layer" and generally all classifiers will give you an output between 0-1.  A sigmoid is a function, not a layer, a function that is applied to the output. Your comment just makes it clear that you are definetly misunderstanding and mixing concepts, thus the answer to your question is 1)it likely already is as sigmoid if its a clasifier 2)you need to sit down and re-read the concepts as you have them a bit mixed.